# how to add css style in table cell dom pdf

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

hi this is my code but margin not working in table cell so please give me some advice .how to add css in "margin" in table cell

```
<html> <head> </head>

<body> <table> <tr>
       <td align="left" valign="top" style="color:#3a3a3c; font-size:14px;margin-left:50px;margin-right:50px;">Lorem ipsum dolor
sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod
tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="27" align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" style="color:#3a3a3c; font-size:14px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna
aliquam erat volutpat.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td height="27" align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
     <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" style="color:#3a3a3c; font-size:14px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna
aliquam erat volutpat.</td>
      </tr> </table>

</body> </html>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. Could you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: Please Clear your question by which any one able to give desire answer

Comment: What do you mean when you say you want to set a margin? Do you want space between the cells or between the cell and its content?

Answer (score 0):

```
<td style="margin:10px"></td>
```